# jQuery removeClass not removing class

Tags: jquery

i have this code:

```
$('.btn-close').click(function(){
    $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
 });
```

I have responsive bar menu, when i open the menu in mobile, it allows two scroll bars, this in menu and body scroll, so first I add class to hide the body overflow, then i wanna to remove this class, but didn`t work. Any solutions?

Comment: Can you include a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: First i add class to the <body>, that disable the body scroll when menu is open and when is close to remove the class

Comment: That's not a Fiddle, that's English.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g1ctooas/1/

Comment: That is not a minimally functional example.  You only have one `<a>` tag called `btn-open`, you do not have a `btn-close` and did not include jQuery as an external resource.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the element that has the class in which do you want to delete. So instead of "body" select the element that has the class "no-scroll":

```
$('.btn-close').click(function(){
    $('ElementThatHasTheClass').removeClass('no-scroll');
 });
```

Comment: First i add class to the <body>, that disable the body scroll when menu is open and when is close to remove the class